# Load or exclude system.webServer modules programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, module

I have developed a website that makes use of a third party DLL.

This DLL has declared an IHttpModule class called AgeGatewayModule.

I do not have access to the source code of the DLL.

In my web.config i declare a configSection & feed in the config properties:

```
<configSections>
<section name="AgeGatewayConfiguration" type="ExternalCompany.AgeGateway.SDK.AgeGatewayConfiguration" />
</configSections>

<AgeGatewayConfiguration
  AgeGatewayUrl="~/Age-Gateway/"
  AccessDeniedUrl="~/Access-Denied/"
  CountryServiceUrl="http://External-Company.svc/v1/" 
LocationServiceUrl="http://External-Company.svc/v1/" 
LdaServiceUrl="http://External-Company.svc/v1/" 
WhiteListingUserAgentsServiceUrl="http://External-Company.svc/v1/UserAgents/" 
WhiteListingReferrersServiceUrl="http://External-Company.svc/v1/Referrers/" 
TokenRealm="http://External-Company.com" 
TokenUserId="xxxx" 
TokenPassword="xxxxxx" 
TokenServiceNamespace="xxxxx" 
TokenAcsHostUrl="accesscontrol.windows.net" 
AllowedGreyCountriesToGlobal="AL" />
```

Finally the module gets added like this:

```
  <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="AgeGatewayModule" type="ExternalCompany.AgeGateway.SDK.AgeGatewayModule, Heineken.AgeGateway.SDK" preCondition="" />
</modules>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

The issue I have is this:

Every time a user visits the website for the first time - that user gets redirected to the age-gateway page.

But i would like that if an admin comes along and requests a certain URL like:

```
 http://my-website/admin/
```

they they would be exempt from filling out the age gateway form. i.e. the redirect would not take place.

The AgeGatewayModule added in the web.config is behind the scenes doing all the checks and redirecting to the age-gateway url if necessary.

So i would like to be able to say something like:

```
if(url != "http://my-website/admin/" || CurrentLoggedInUser != admin)
{
//load the AgeGatewayModule only now)
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not the solution, but might be interesting [Register your HTTP modules at runtime without config](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/register-your-http-modules-at-runtime.html)

Comment: Thanks @MennanKara - It is interesting - but it seems that solution is geared towards MVC and not webforms. My code breaks and throws a namespace error on Infrastructure at System.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule

Comment: I've searched for a solution to limit httpmodules to certain paths with no luck before. If you find a solution, please share with us, thanks.

Comment: @MennanKara - Still looking - no other replies yet. Will let you know if I find anything. Not looking good at the moment.. Thanks

Comment: Actually, you can wrap the 3rd party module class in your own class and add the path limitations to your class in the code, what do you think?